# Understand txdata in ethereum

Tags: hex

I have the following output:

> initialize(string,string,uint8), txdata: 0x1624f6c6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, value: 0x0

So what I'm understanding is that the length of the txdata is 264 is the total of string, string and uint8.

But it seems to me it's wrong when I try to split the length of each parameter. Am I right in this case?

Comment: Can you give the value of the three inputs ?

Comment: @clement it just displays 0x0 as the value, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#examples

`0x1624f6c6` is the Method ID

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040` is the first parameter

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060` is the second one

and so on